# Inconsistent behavior of Min() and Max() on a varchar column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `MyTable` in which the below are the three major columns.

```
ContactId | QuestionId | ResponseValue
   8           31         Ankush Agro
   8           32         Pramod Gho
   9           31         Pawansut K S K
   9           32         sandip mor
```

The above `ResponseValue` column is a dynamic column. i.e. 
The response value changes as per the question id which refers from a questionmaster.

In other words this is what the table indirectly represents,

```
ContactId  |    Question    |     ResponseValue
   8           Shop Name          Ankush Agro
   8           Owner Name         Pramod Gho
   9           Shop Name          Pawansut K S K
   9           Owner Name         sandip mor
```

So now my requirement is that i need each Question Name in the questions column 
as a column header. i.e. `Pivot` the Table on Shop Name and Owner name.
Since an aggregate function cannot be used on non-numeric column i am using `min()` and `Max()` functions

Like this,

```
Select
max(Case MyTable.QuestionID When  '31' Then ResponseValue else 'N/A' End) [Shop Name],
max(Case MyTable.QuestionID When  '32' Then ResponseValue else 'N/A' End) [Owner Name]
from MyTable
left join QuestionMaster on QuestionMaster.QuestionId=  MyTable.QuestionId
where MyTable.QuestionId in (31,32)
```

The **Problem** that i am facing is,
if I use `Max()` on shopname only the second records' shopname value is displayed but the first records is 'N/A'

```
Shop Name      |    Owner Name
Pawansut K S K      sandip mor
   N/A              Pramod Gho
```

And when i use `Min()` Vice Versa happens

```
Shop Name      |    Owner Name
   N/A              sandip mor
Ankush Agro         Pramod Gho
```

Can some one give me an insight of why this is happening?

This is how i want my query to give the resultset

```
  Shop Name      |  Owner Name
   Pawansut K S K       sandip mor
    Ankush Agro         Pramod Gho
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag since you appear to be using SQL Server.

Comment: Please show the _exact_ output you expect.  I think you are confused about how a pivot query works.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The answer that you previously posted worked for me

Comment: OK I brought it back, but I was a bit confused about your question, because it is not how I would think about this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pivot query has a problem.  You should be using `NULL` values in the `ELSE` portion of the `CASE` expressions:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN t1.QuestionID = '31'
                         THEN t1.ResponseValue ELSE NULL END), 'N/A') AS [Shop Name],
       COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN t1.QuestionID = '32'
                         THEN t1.ResponseValue ELSE NULL END), 'N/A') AS [Owner Name]
FROM MyTable t1
LEFT JOIN QuestionMaster t2
    ON t2.QuestionId = t1.QuestionId
WHERE t1.QuestionId IN (31, 32)
GROUP BY t1.QuestionId
```